# Preview document history

Tags: preview

I seemingly open 5 documents for every one document I close in preview (I do a lot of reading with preview).

Is there a way to have preview reopen all of the documents I had opened last time it was closed (for example, when I want to restart my computer to grab an update), regardless of the number of opened documents? Sometimes the history just isn't enough for me or the history doesn't reflect what I presently have open.

If not, can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat Reader has an option to open PDFs from the last session. You may give that a test drive since it's free. Launch Acrobat Reader and go to the file menu. 2nd option down reads "Reopen PDFs from last session". This may do what you want.